# How can we get youtube Developers key and client ID..?

Tags: youtube-api

I am integrating YouTube API in Flex using below reference 
https://www.flextras.com/DataSorter/Samples/YouTubeSample/#app=d6b7&241c-selectedIndex=1
This module requires a "Developers Key" and "Client ID"
How can we get youtube Developers key and client ID..?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can get them in the APIs Console:

[APIs Console](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=devconsole&passive=1209600&continue=https://code.google.com/apis/console/&followup=https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

Some information about the APIs Console:

https://developers.google.com/console/help/

Answer (score 0):

The Youtube video that I have created is at https://youtu.be/nBdCmeNqqJ0 which will guide you to create your **Client ID** and **Developer key** i.e. `Client secret` and enable **YouTube DATA API v3** `which will allow you to use Youtube DATA API V3 service`.

**OR**

Have a look at the below gif.

[image: https://s23.aconvert.com/convert/p3r68-cdx67/3fjqk-nr656.gif]

Actually, I have converted an AVI file `(which tells the steps to create Client ID, Client secret)` to Gif online.

So better is to download and save the gif somewhere properly if you want to have it as it can be remove later by site owner.

Thanks.